# common table expression to fetch data from columns with particular word

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a temp table with following data: `col1` is a `varchar` and `col2` is `int identity`

```
col1                       col2
------------------------------------
null                        1
null                        2
task=call client            3
startdate=05062015          4
a                           5
fgfg                        6
task=leave a msg            7
startdate=06062015          8
```

I need to write a CTE to fetch data from columns that begin with task , and their respective startdate

This is the output that I need:

```
task                       startdate
--------------------------------------------
task=call client           05062015
task=leave a msg           06062015
```

Can someone please help me with this ?

I have come up with this so far:

```
;with cte (txt) 
as 
( 
    select col1 from #temp where col1 like 'task%'
) 
select * from CTE
```

So far it's working fine and I'm getting the below output:

```
txt
---
task=call client 
task= leave a msg
```

I'm stuck with how to implement the `startdate` in the CTE:

I have written the below query:

```
startdate = substring(col1,11,20) 
from #temp 
where col2 > (select top 1 col2 
              from #temp 
              where col1 like 'task%' ) and col1 like '%startdate%'
```

Comment: What have **you tried** so far? Please show us some effort of your own

Comment: i have come up with this

;with cte (txt)
as
(
select txt from #temp where col1 like 'task%') select * from CTE 


till here its working fine im geitng the below output

task=call client
task= leave a msg


im stuck with how to implement the startdate in the CTE

i have below query written 
startdate = substring(col1,11,20) from #temp where col2> (select top 1 col2 from #temp where txt like 'task%' ) and txt like '%startdate%'

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: why do you have %startdate% wouldnt startdate% be enough?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a CTE - a simple join will be fine:

```
SELECT T1.col1 AS [Task],
    SUBSTRING(T2.col1,10,8) AS [Startdate]
FROM
    #temp T1
INNER JOIN
    #temp T2 WHERE T1.col2 + 1 = T2.col2
WHERE
    T1.col1 like 'task%'
```

This assumes, of course, that every record with "task=..." in col1 is immediately followed by a record with a startdate, in col2 order.

Comment: what if col1 is not followed by a record with a startdate ?

Comment: Then you might get an error with this code. What do you want the output to be, when a task record is not immediately followed by a startdate record?

Comment: there are certain records that are not immediately followed by startdate,

the output desired remains the same

Comment: Will there be more task record between a task record and start date?

Comment: How do you define which start date for a given task?

Comment: for every task , startdate follows either immediately or after few records

Comment: u have a task and then a startdate, and again a task followed by startdate